# Event log in in worker service not published to Azure Application Insight

Tags: azure, windows-services, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-3.1, event-log

I am building a *Worker Service* as *Windows Service*. I use `EventLog` for logging. I also want to add `ApplicationInsights` to log the events. I follow this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service , install the SDK using Nuget and setup everything as requested. Here is my `program.cs` configuration.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)                
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
                services.CustomeDependencyInjection();
            })
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.AddEventLog(eventLogSetting =>
                {
                    eventLogSetting.LogName = "MyTestEventLog";
                    eventLogSetting.SourceName = "MyTestEventApp";
                });
            });
```

Here is the `appsetting.json` file

```
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
      "InstrumentationKey": "bd******-****-****-****-***********b"
  },
  Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Information",
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    },
    "EventLog": {
      "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an logging example in the `worker.cs` file

```
public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, TelemetryClient tc)
{
        _logger = logger;
        this.tc = tc;
 }
 public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
        this._logger.LogInformation("In Start");
        using (tc.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("Operation"))
        {
            /** 
                my service starting code 
            **/
            this._logger.LogInformation("Service is being started");
            tc.TrackEvent("Worker service starting operation completed.");
        }
        this._logger.LogInformation( "Service Started");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
 }
```

When I run the application, I can see a `customEvent`. I can also see `request` event. But I cannot find anything in the `trace` where I was expecting the info sent using `_logger`. I checked the output window and also did not find any telemetry is sent against the `_logger.LogInformation`.

What am I doing wrong in here and how can I make the Logger Info available to the `ApplicationInsights`? Or am I not looking into the right place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application Insight defaults to `Warning` as the log level. Since you are tracing with level `Information` you need to configure application insights using the appsettings.json file:

```json
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
      "InstrumentationKey": "bd******-****-****-****-***********b"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
    "EventLog": {
        "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}
```