# Null reference exception in Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Workerservice.dll

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

In a .dll I have got a method to send an Azure Event.

It runs, when I call it from an executable.
When I call it from an from an plug in, I get Null reference exception from the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Workerservice.dll
These are the lines, where it happens:

```
*TelemetryConfiguration configuration = new TelemetryConfiguration(orchestrationKeyToUse);
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, KnaufCustomTelemetryInitializer>();
**services.interface call(orchestrationKeyToUse);***
```

In the bold line it throws the exeption.

I tried to call it from the plugin in a interface call and I tried to start a thread to call the method. In both cases it throws an exception. Called from an executable, it runs without problems. Any ideas, why?

Comment: You can refer to [Application Insights for Worker Service applications (non-HTTP applications)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service) and [Event log in in worker service not published to Azure Application Insight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65565879/event-log-in-in-worker-service-not-published-to-azure-application-insight). You can also open an issue on GitHub [microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues)

Answer (score -3):

Thank you [Fildor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982149/fildor). Posting your suggestions as answer to help other community members.

The  `runtime`  throwing a  `NullReferenceException`  **always**  means the same thing: you are trying to use a reference, and the reference is not initialized (or it was  *once*  initialized, but is  *no longer*  initialized). This means the reference is  `null`, and you cannot access members (such as methods) through a  `null`  reference. A `NullReferenceException` will be raised in the case of early-created controls with event handlers.

That fire during  `InitializeComponent`  which reference late-created controls.  Below example will give information about Initializing component.

```xml
<Grid>
    <!-- Combobox declared first -->
    <ComboBox Name="comboBox1" 
              Margin="10"
              SelectedIndex="0" 
              SelectionChanged="comboBox1_SelectionChanged">
       <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
       <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 2" />
       <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 3" />
    </ComboBox>
        
    <!-- Label declared later -->
    <Label Name="label1" 
           Content="Label"
           Margin="10" />
</Grid>
```

Here  `comboBox1`  is created before  `label1`. If  `comboBox1_SelectionChanged`  attempts to reference `label1, it will not yet have been created.

```cs
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Content = comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString(); // NullReferenceException here!!
}
```

Changing the order of the declarations in the  `XAML`  (i.e., listing  `label1`  before  `comboBox1`, ignoring issues of design philosophy) would at least resolve the  `NullReferenceException`  here.

Check the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660186/15969833) for further details.

Comment: How does it even remotely answer OP's question?! It's pretty obvious that OP knows well what NullReferenceException means. The question is why it is *not* thrown from executable and thrown from plugin. Theoretical explanation of `XAML` controls is not only irrelevant to the question, but also very condescending